# What happens when child thread crash and main wait for join?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

In the following program I created a `pthread_t` thread1 which crash in function `func()` . I am interested in what exactly happened for `pthread_join` command in `main()` .

I ran below program and in exited normally by printing "complete". I dont know why?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <map> 
#include <cstring> 
#include <climits> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include<pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 

void* func(void *data)
{
    cout<<"Calling func"<<(long)(data)<<endl;
    int *a;
    cout<<a[2]<<endl;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main( )
{ 
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create(&thread1, 0 , &func, (void*)2);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    cout<<"complete"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: You invoked undefined behavior. You were (un)lucky the program continued and appeared as if all was right in the universe. Thus the nature of UB.

Comment: @WhozCraig Which part in there is "undefined"?

Comment: @GhostCat Dereferencing an indeterminate pointer, for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the threads operate mostly independent, meaning that each thread can use a signal-handler to catch a "crash"-signal without having the other threads to be killed aswell. Therefor signal-handlers needs to be added.

source: signal-manpage http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole
>          (e.g., when sent using kill(2)) or for a specific thread (e.g.,
>          certain signals, such as SIGSEGV and SIGFPE, generated as a
>          consequence of executing a specific machine-language instruction are
>          thread directed, as are signals targeted at a specific thread using
>          pthread_kill(3)).  A process-directed signal may be delivered to any
>          one of the threads that does not currently have the signal blocked.
>          If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the
>          kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.

Comment: That only applies if the `SIGSEGV` has a handler installed, in which case the thread did not "crash" - it entered the signal handler.  If the thread really did crash (no signal handler installed) then the entire process is killed.

Answer (score 7):

The process itself will segfault in your case.

If you were to assign NULL to `a` you can see that it will crash in all likelyhood. In the current code you invoke `a` in non deterministic manner. Some random location is referenced by `a`. Hence behavior is undefined. Sometimes you will see the log statement in `main`, other times the program will crash. Consider yourself lucky if program crashes on such executions

If the thread does a NULL pointer de-reference, it will take the whole process down. Its a process crash and not a thread crash.

Comment: "If you were to assign NULL to a you can see that it will crash definitely" No, not definitely. It is still undefined behaviour.

Comment: @jaunchopanza, agree. The likelihood of process crash with null-pointer deference is far greater non-null deference. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Prabhu Yes, whole program is crashing in case of NULL de-referencing So, if a thread crashed then whole process craches. Right?

Comment: @Domso Prabhu's NULL de-reference point is valid. I tried at my end.

Comment: @Domso, I get your point. And thanks for the references. In the absence of signal handlers which does specific book-keeping to terminate gracefully, the entire process will terminate. (yes, may be the thread "crashed", but the main thread won't continue to be alive)

Comment: @Domso: This example does not have a signal handler installed for `SIGSEGV`, so a segmentation fault in any thread will indeed terminate the entire process.